# Can a mobile friendly site with adsense qualify as not mobile friendly?

Tags: google-adsense, mobile

I don't get it.

According to http://www.monetizemore.com/blog/best-ad-sizes-for-mobile-devices-in-2015/, Google would label a URL as mobile-friendly if it believes it is mobile-friendly.

When I check my pages through page-speed insights, I never get a complaint about mobile usability issues except for issues related to elements in adsense ads themselves. Issues I receive from page-speed insights that all pertain to ads are "Size tap-targets appropiately", "Minify Javascript", "Leverage browser caching". Some of these issues change depending on the ad that is loaded.

Is it possible that a mobile site with adsense ads could cause google to believe it's not mobile-friendly when users search for the site online? Or am I just over-thinking things?

Comment: The "minify JavaScript" and the "browser caching" are issues that arise for every external script you load. Facebook buttons, Google plus buttons, etc all come with JavaScript with a near future cache expiry. It does not make the site less mobile friendly, but the phone has to download the same data more often reducing the speed of the page load. Pagespeed is a tool and the only way to overcome this issue is to host all JavaScript yourself. (But then you would always risk serving an outdated version.) The tap target size is different and strange as I that is something Google injects.

Answer (score 1):

As long the page/site is following the necessary page and SEO best practice. Too many ads on a page needs to be tested with the FETCH and RENDER feature in Google Search Console. So ideally avoid too many ads towards the top half of the page.

Comment: Since a few years ago, I've stuck with only one ad unit maximum per page. My adsense financial situation has improved so I think my adsense arrangement is OK, at least for now.